# Help writing where portion of query in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I have a query written using codeigniters active record class.

When the query is written it looks like

```
WHERE `account` = 1 
AND cgl.contactId IS NULL 
AND `firstName` LIKE 'M%' 
OR `lastName` LIKE 'M%'
```

But I need it to look like

```
WHERE `account` = 1 
AND cgl.contactId IS NULL 
AND (`firstName` LIKE 'M%' 
OR `lastName` LIKE 'M%') //notice the brackets
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$this->where(array('account' => 1, 'cgl.contactId' => NULL);
$this->where(("firstName` LIKE 'M%' OR `lastName` LIKE 'M%'"))
```

Comment: damn, was hoping I wouldn't have to do this.